# Can't boot MacBook Pro after downgrade from High Sierra to Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, downgrade, high-sierra

My MacBook Pro (2014) can not start after downgrade from macOS 10.13 to 10.12 via USB.

I don't known why I had clover on my MacBook. Right now, my MacBook starts up with a light screen and doesn't show anything. Keyboard caps lock and USB don't work.

Comment: I did try anything. But not work. Right now i don't know to format my ssd.

Comment: I use mac 10.13 beta. I downgrade to 10.12 via usb. After intsall success. I don't know why clover bootloader show. I were force shutdown. Anh i could startup ever again

Comment: I use mobilephone to find anyway to fix this problem.

Comment: Please add any step you already performed (SMC/NVRAM reset etc) to solve your problem to your question and **not** in the comments! Please remove your comments afterwards.

Comment: **We** know even less than **you** why Clover is installed on your Mac! So **you** have to explain it to the community...

Comment: Where did you get the 10.12 USB? Apple Store or *'somewhere else'*? My guess is it was 'somewhere else' & was meant for a Hackintosh, not a real Mac.

Comment: Can you boot into target disk mode? If you can, there’s a way, or Apple’s the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for all response. I will bring my macbook to apple center to fixed.